# Getting unique IDs for Android calendar Events

Tags: android, icalendar, android-calendar

I've done quite a bit of research, and can't find how to access a truly unique ID for Calendar events int Android. I query the following `URI`:

```
Context.getContentResolver().query(Events.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

When looking through the resulting `Cursor` on my Galaxy Nexus, there is nothing similar to the `iCalGUID` form (see below) that I am looking for. However, when doing the same query on an HTC One S, I noticed that HTC has included `iCalGUID` as an extra column field, which returns exactly the type of ID that I'm looking for. It looks like this:

```
9ced5c2c-6ed9-481f-9f69-9a064810ac0f
```

It doesn't look like this `iCalGUID` field is Android SDK standard, though, so I can't get this ID on other Android phones. My question is, is there some way I can get this type of ID in a way that is standard Android? I'm targetting ICS right now, but would like to be flexible to extend this to previous versions in the future.

If there is some other type of ID that I should be using, that would be great as well. **NOTE**: I am *not* looking for the `Events._ID` column. I need my IDs to be unique across all devices, and all types of `Account`s (Google, Exchange, Hotmail, etc.)

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, did you find your answer?

Answer (score 2):

The Field [UID_2445](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#UID_2445) was intended for this purpose, but unfortunately it is almost never populated, and [never with an actual UID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312725/unique-calendar-event-uid-2445-getting-null).

Synchronisers can access various sync fields which in my testing always hold the event original id. The problem is the fields populated depend on the particular synchroniser, there isn't a standard. You'll need the synchroniser read permission to look at those fields.

It's not supported and I don't recommend it but you could look at account type (e.g com.android.exchange) to figure out the synchroniser then look in the field usually populated with the UID. In my testing it's Sync Data 2 for everything but Google, which is Sync Data 1.