# unique calendar event UID_2445 getting null

Tags: calendar, unique, android-calendar

According to the android developer forum on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html
the field UID_2445 should be available from API 17 to grant a unique calendar id.
However, I'm getting null for the event id. 
tried on 4.2.1, 4.2.2
tried on google event, exchange event
Has anyone manager to get a value for this field?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Apparently it's a bug, there's a report here, please vote up https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68398&q=event%20uid&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: Since that bug was incorrectly closed, as I have reproduced this on the Android M Preview, as well as 4.4 KitKat and 5.1 Lollipop, I filed a new bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179301 Please star.

Comment: Any further news on this? I'm still seeing null in Android 7.x