# Custom Unique Identifier calendar event

Tags: android-calendar

I want to assign unique ids to events so I can query them (for example to avoid re-insert the event if it's already inserted). I can't see any event property for this use (`calendar_id` is setted automatically). I would like to avoid the use of a `calendar_id <=> my_id` relation of my own, using my api or whatever.

So, the question is: can I assign an unique identifier to an event so I can query for it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. There is a field called `UID_2445`. According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#UID_2445):

> The UID for events added from the RFC 2445 iCalendar format. Column
>   name.

However you can use this column to assign a unique identifier. Also you can use other sync columns listed in `CalendarContract.EventsColumns`.

Comment: It has a bug in it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312725/unique-calendar-event-uid-2445-getting-null